# how to remove adjacent alphabets from string?

Tags: java, algorithm

remove all two sequenced alphabets from sequence, and leave with the least where no more combination can be removed

For example

```
XCDCDY  -> XCDY > XY > empty  (cant be transformed further)

DCBDE  -> DCB > D (cant be transformed further)
```

any suggestions or ideas please to solve this problem. Not able to think how alphabets sequence can be handled programmatically.

Comment: Minor note on wording: "alphabet" is the whole thing from "abc..." to "...xyz". A single element of an alphabet is a letter (there's also "character" which is wider and includes digits). So you want to remove adjacent letters from the string.

Comment: What's the rule for the DCB to D transformation?  Couldn't it just as easily be DCB to B?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I had misunderstood the question at first... here's the updated version. It became a little complex, but couldn't find a simpler way to do it:

```
public class StringTransformation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "XCDCDY";
        String sequenceToRemove = getSequenceToRemove(input);
        String remainingChars = input;
        System.out.println(remainingChars);

        while (isTransformable(remainingChars, sequenceToRemove) && remainingChars.contains(sequenceToRemove) && sequenceToRemove.length() > 1) {
            String tmp = remainingChars.replaceFirst(sequenceToRemove, "");
            remainingChars = tmp;
            sequenceToRemove = getSequenceToRemove(remainingChars);
            System.out.println(remainingChars);
        }
        System.out.println("cant be transformed further");
    }

    public static boolean isTransformable(String input, String toBeRemoved) {
        if (input.replace(toBeRemoved, "").length() >= 1) {
            return true;
        } else if (input.length() == 2 && input.contentEquals(toBeRemoved)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String getSequenceToRemove(String characters) {
        char[] chars = characters.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder tmpString = new StringBuilder();
        int index = 1;
        for (char ch : chars) {
            if (chars.length > index) {
                if (chars[index] - ch == 1 && tmpString.length() < 2) {
                    tmpString.append(ch);
                    tmpString.append(chars[index]);
                }
                if (tmpString.length() == 2) {
                   break;
                }
            } else if (chars.length == 2 && chars[1] - chars[0] == 1) {
                tmpString = new StringBuilder(chars[0] + String.valueOf(chars[1]));
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return tmpString.toString();
    }
}
```

This code will output:

```
XCDCDY
XCDY
XY

cant be transformed further
```

Basically the logic behind it is that if you have a sequence like **'AB'**, **B** minus **A** will be equal 1, because of the ANSI values for each character.
The ANSI value of B is 66 and A is 65.

Comment: Why you put duplicate alphabet manually in `toBeRemoved` variable?

Comment: I did not look into your _solution_. But as a general hint: This question does not show any effort or reasearch, and it is not clear enough. Thus is shouldn't be answered but better be deleted. This is Q&A site, and this question is not going to help any further reader.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I saw your comment too late, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej  I had misunderstood the question at first... it's not clear enough. But I updated my answer with new code... check it out